# Maven dependancy Autoit

Tags: java, maven, webdriver, autoit

Is there dependancy for AutoIt for Maven related pom.xml. I have that autoit related .EXE to close Print window. I want to call from WebDriver (Java) code.

```
I tried this, but did not work:

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.holmos</groupId>
            <artifactId>holmos-webtest</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2u10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a library available in Maven but found this, https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/07/02/selenium-autoit-how-to-automate-non-browser-based-functionality/

Comment: Are you looking for [AutoItX4Java](https://github.com/sixtoad/autoitx4java)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.openkeyword</groupId>
    <artifactId>autoit</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.20</version>
</dependency>
```